# What does the double slash mean in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've found this piece in a script

```
var name = project.SMALL_WIDTH//p.containerWidth() /// 2//project.WIDTH / 4
```

What do the double and the triple slash mean?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `///` is (most likely) there only to divide up parts of the comment. But, they don't have any affect in the code. Everything after a `//` in a JavaScript code is not rendered by the browser. You could do this and it would still work:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
// Hello! I'm a comment! ///////////////// these slashes don't do anything as they're in a comment.
// The double slashes tell the browser not to render it.
</script>
```

Also, you can do multiple line comments:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
/*
This is a 
multiple 
line 
comment!
*/
</script>
```

As you can see, multiple line comments in JavaScript are very similar to CSS comments.

Answer (score 8):

The double slash is a comment. Triple slash doesn't mean anything special, but it might be a comment that was added right before a division.

```
var a = 10 / 2;
var a = 10 /// 2;
```

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: Those are just comments. Let them go.

Long answer: In most of the programming languages, anything written after a `//` on the same line of code is treated as single line comments.

There is also something called as multi-line comments. 
The start and end of a multi-line comment is denoted by `/*` and `*/` respectively.

Example:

`var a = 1; //This is a single line comment`

`var b = 2;
/*
This 
is 
a 
multi-line
comment
*/`