# Why is 2 /// 2 is 2 in Javascript?

Tags: javascript

Does anyone know why `2 /// 2` is `2` in Javascript?

What is this behavior called? Is it documented somewhere? Thanks.

Comment: Why downvote the question? While it is easy to answer, it is perfectly valid for someone not extremely familiar with programming. And some languages such as python even have a `//` operator (well ok, comments are not started with `//` there)

Comment: You'd better upload that part of code so we can see the context. After // it is comment. So script wont be computed.

Comment: @Sang: While this is usually true, in this case the question contains everything necessary. No need for a testcase in a JSFiddle (besides that, only a testcase where the JS engine displayed you parser tokens would help...)

Comment: Why using a syntax highlighter can be incredibly useful. Especially for when people have dumped old code in multi-line comments.

Comment: @ThiefMaster I meant if he uploaded more code then we might give more precise insight that what author means by that.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8143477/jquery-double-slash

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The answer is simple: single-line comment. The first two slashes begin a comment so the whole statement is just `2`

Answer (score 15):

It's called commenting. Anything that starts with `//` is a single-line comment.

Your code is essentially `2` as the rest of the line is a comment of "`/ 2`".

Answer (score 10):

`//` introduces a single line comment in JavaScript

Answer (score 7):

That is called a comment:

```
2 /// 2
```

Is equal to:

```
2
```

Because everything after and including the `//` is ignored (until a newline). JavaScript also has this horrible feature where it automatically inserts semicolons before newlines so that the code doesn't fail when you do something like this:

```
var x = 2 /// 2
```

---

BTW: use a text editor with syntax highlighting.

Comment: nice explanation, I was intimidated by the look of the expression and forgot about *comments*