# What does /// mean in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

The double forward slash `//` is a comment in JavaScript, but what does a triple forward slash `///` mean?  The reason I am asking is the code breaks when I remove a line that has `///`. Which leads me to believe that `///` is not a comment.

Comment: Nothing special... Could you elaborate a little?

Comment: A comment that starts with a `/`.

Comment: "a line that has ///" - perhaps it's useful to post that line of code to see where it appears and what it does.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What does the double slash mean in JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8143477/what-does-the-double-slash-mean-in-javascript)

Comment: Can you elaborate on the 'code breaks'? Doxygen uses triple slashes for comments, is that somehow integrated into your project? The more information you can provide, the better-- what are you doing with JavaScript, what frameworks, a snippet?

Comment: anything after "//" is still a comment on the same line. You could ask the question, what is "//(infinity)" mean as well. Same answer.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Could be a [reference directive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17139800/what-is-this-javascript-reference-syntax-used-in-visual-studio)

Does it look like this?

```
/// <reference path="jquery-1.8.2.js" />
```

Answer (score 7):

These are all comments:

```
//
// ..............
//..............
// //////////////
////////////////
///
/// ..............
```

since the comment extends from the `//` to the end of the line.

**Edited to add:** Of course, there are various contexts where neither `//` nor `///` introduces a comment. For example:

```
'///'       <-- this is a string
"///"       <-- this is a string (same as previous)
/[///]/     <-- this is a regular expression (same as /\//)
/* /// */   <-- this is a comment delimited by /*...*/
/\///3      <-- this is /\// divided by 3, i.e., not-a-number
```

Answer (score 1):

A commented out slash character in the code.

If it is in a regular expression, please provide the context/complete line of code to allow quality explanations to be provided.

Comment: In a regular expression, a plain `///` is syntactically invalid. When you use the RegExp constructor to create a RegEx, `///` is no more special than `abc`.

Comment: Not necessarily. `/[///]/.test("/") === true`, pointless but no errors.

Comment: @both commenters - true, hence why we need a more precise example to determine the actual usage outside a simple commented slash character.

Answer (score 1):

In Javascript anything that begins with at least 2 //, is a comment, adding one more would make no difference as far as the code not working.

Answer (score 1):

anything after "//" is still a comment on the same line. You could ask the question, what does "//(infinity)" mean? Same answer. Comments.

There maybe specialized programs that interpret JS on the fly and do special things with "///" but that is outside the scope of this question.