# What is /this type of comment/? Can't find even mentions of it

Tags: javascript, comments

While making a small thingy in javascript, I found that I could make comments `/like these/`

Because stack overflow's code doesn't color them, here's an image:
[image: comment poetry at its finest]

I haven't found anything about them, and I think they may have an extremely specific name and usage, because in no answer regarding comments I was able to find mentions of it.

For more specifity, I was using google's App Script, but because their documentation doesn't say anything about single slash comments, I doubt it is related to said IDE.

Also, I say it is a comment because when putting it in the middle of my code it acts like one, but the fact it's affected by the return shows it isn't really a comment, and leaves me even more clueless.

Any input or clue to continue searching would be greatly appreciated!

Edit:
Indeed it wasn't a comment, it is instead a weird unused expression, that JS understood as a comment in the specific situation it was in. 
Also I'd like to point out the speed of the answerer; I refreshed the page to fix a typo and it was already answered in clear detail, thanks!

Edit 2:
Now knowing that it is an expression, I can see that a few of the things I found when looking for them, indeed mentioned them, for example [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9572158/13972080) briefly noted that `/[///]/` is an expression, but I confused the meaning of expression as "normal code" instead of [the object meant for matching string patterns](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Single forward slashes delimit regular expressions, eg:

```js
console.log(/abc/.test('fooabc'));
```

And unused expressions are permitted in JavaScript, though they're often confusing and shouldn't be used:

```js
/abc/; // unused regular expression literal
```

The "comment style" you're seeing is a long regular expression literal, whose resulting expression isn't being used.

```js
/why would you ever do this/;
/please don't/
console.log('program running');
```

I highly recommend against doing this in code anyone will have to maintain - it looks extremely strange. Maybe useful for something like a trivia question, but not for anything serious. Consider the ESLint rule [no-unused-expressions](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-unused-expressions).