# What does a double division sign do in Javascript?

Tags: javascript

What does a double division sign do?

```
d8> 3//2
3
d8> 3//10
3
d8> 10//3
10
d8> 1000//6
1000
```

Why does it just return the dividend every time?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is self-evident.

Comment: It's a [comment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Lexical_grammar#Comments).

Comment: possible duplicate of [What does the double slash mean in JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8143477/what-does-the-double-slash-mean-in-javascript)

Comment: @Mathletics: hilarious.

Comment: Given that [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1642028/what-is-the-name-of-this-operator) is the highest-voted question in the `C` tag, I don't think this is terrible...

Comment: How did you manage to type in these four examples without noticing the pattern?

Comment: @Kay Hint: It's how I got the answer. Hahaha.

Comment: @PatrickCollins: voters in the C tag being awful doesn't make this question any better.

Comment: @Kay Because I was using a terminal, which doesn't do syntax highlighting

Answer (score 9):

Nothing. It's a line comment. It disregards the `//` and everything after it.

Comment: @goodcow We all are at some point in time. And we become awesome at another point as well. :D